# How I can serialize information across 3 tables in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 tables(2 tables are belonging to 1 table using ForeignKey).
I could create queryset across 3 tables. However, I cannot get naming table information from serialized return data as below.
Could anyone tell me how I should revise serializer?

[image] 
**views.py**

```
class lightData(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = lightSerializer
    pagination_class = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        certificate = self.kwargs['certificate']
        return Light.objects.prefetch_related('zone__namingzone')
```

**models.py**

```
class Zone(models.Model):
    zone=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    conditioned=models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.zone

class Light(models.Model):
    zone=models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='lightzone')
    lpd=models.IntegerField()
    sensor=models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('certificate', 'zone'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.certificate)+"_"+str(self.zone)

class Naming(models.Model):
    zone=models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='namingzone')
    naming=models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.zone)+"_"+self.naming
```

**serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Certificate,Zone,Light,OA,Naming

class zoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Zone
        fields = ('zone','conditioned')

class lightSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    zone = zoneSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model=Light
        fields = ('zone','lpd','sensor')

class namingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    zone=zoneSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model=Naming
        fields=('zone','naming')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new serializer, **`NamingNewSerializer`** and add it inside your **`zoneSerializer`** as below,

```
class NamingNewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Naming
        fields = '__all__'


class zoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    namingzone = NamingNewSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Zone
        fields = ('zone', 'conditioned', 'namingzone')
```

---

here the **`namingzone`** is the ***reverse relation keyword*** which is used to fetch/get **`Naming`** instances from a single **`Zone`** instance.

---

Apart from that, I suggest you to follow the [**CapWords convention**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) while name your classes :)